# failed to copy a shell script from host to a vagrant box

Tags: puppet, vagrant

Host is Windows 8
I prepared a shell script which execute secure_mysql_installation 
This is the folders structure

```
c:\myproject\
      Vagranfile
      puppet\
          files\
             secure_mysql.sh
          mainfests\
             init.pp
```

This is my  puppet code to copy the local host shell script to vagrant box

```
    class secure_mysql_installation {
        file { '/tmp/secure_mysql.sh':
                source => 'puppet:///files/secure_mysql.sh',
                ensure => present,
               }
     }
```

When vagrant up, it gave me an error
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Secure_mysql_installation/File[/tmp/secure_mysq
l.sh]: Could not evaluate: Cannot find file: Invalid mount 'secure_mysql.sh' Cou
ld not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///files/secure_mysql.sh: Cannot find file: I
nvalid mount 'secure_mysql.sh'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the guest, that folder is going to be at `/vagrant/puppet/files`, but you don't want to use that at all since it doesn't translate from vagrant to everywhere else. The answer by @deagh starts to lead you in the right direction. You need to move any files into a modules folder.

So

```
c:\myproject\
      Vagranfile
      puppet\
          modules\
             mymodulename\
               files\
                 secure_mysql.sh
          mainfests\
             init.pp
```

And then you can reach it with

```
 class secure_mysql_installation {
    file { '/tmp/secure_mysql.sh':
            source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodulename/secure_mysql.sh',
            ensure => present,
           }
 }
```

For more information about file serving and mount points, please see https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `source` definition lacks the module name try

`source => 'puppet:///modules/[MODULENAME]/secure_mysql.sh',`

Comment: While this is technically the right answer, you may need to state that files should be under a module folder.

Comment: Yes and to be even more precise i have to say that your file should be placed under '[MODULENAME]/files/'